# Why does comparing a string literal and an integer return a warning of comparison between pointer and integer?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main()
{
   int c;
   c=getchar();
   if(c=="a")
   {
    printf("fizz");
   }
   else
    printf("buzz");
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:8:8: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
    if(c=="a")
```

As I understand it, if the string literal `"a"` was assigned to a variable name `a[1]` and the comparison was made  `c==a[0]` then the variable name would implicitly decay into *a(0) which is a pointer to the first element in the array. But without a variable name how is the string literal `"a"` read as a pointer. Does the compiler itself assign a pointer to this string to execute the comparison?

Comment: because "a" is a char array

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, true, comment written too fast. Anyway answer below answers the question. I delete the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals have type "array of `char`".  And like any array, when one is used in an expression it *decays* (in most cases) to a pointer to its first element.

So the comparison `c=="a"` is comparing an `int` on the left and a `char *` on the right, hence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

String literal is `const char` array which decays to a pointer.

So your code is almost identical to this one

```
   const char a[] = "a";
   c=getchar();
   if(c==a)
```

You need to use character constant

```
   c=getchar();
   if(c=='a')
```

or index the string literal

```
   c=getchar();
   if(c=="a"[0])
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but in C string literals have type `char[]`. Not to be confused with C++ where they have type `const char[]`. This is a known language bug in C.